# ema(X,window=2) vs ewmMean(X,span=2,adjust=false) in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I got a question on DolphinDB functions `ema` and `ewaMean` . The results of `ema(X,window=2)` and `ewmMean(X,span=2,adjust=false)` as shown in the pictures were different at first, but appeared consistent gradually.

Why are the results different?

[image: ema result]

[image: ewaMean result]

Answer (score 1):

When you set adjust=false in `ewmMean`, the formula is basically the same with that of `ema`.

The difference lies in the initial value (k = 0) and the calculation is different when k < window.

When k < window, the result of `ema` is NULL.

When k = window, EMA(X)k=mean(X[:k]).

Differently, `ewmMean` replaces `EMA(X)k` with x0 when k = 0, so no NULL value is generated.

The influence of the initial values gradually decays, and the difference between the results also decreases.